# process SIGABRT when PortableServer::ServantLocator preinvoke() returns CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST()

Tags: c++, corba, ace, tao

The following is the extract of the class I use which inherits from PortableServer::ServantLocator class in TAO. When the overridden method of preinvoke() is being invoked, if the servant is NULL (which has been destroyed prior to this instance), I throw CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST() exception back, as shown below

```
class Locator : public PortableServer::ServantLocator {
    public:
        PortableServer::Servant preinvoke(
                const PortableServer::ObjectId& oid,
                PortableServer::POA_ptr         adapter,
                const char *                    operation,
                Cookie&                         cookie ) throw ()
        {
            .
            .
            .// retrieve servant
            .
            if (servant == NULL) {
                //return NULL;
                throw CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST ();
            }
            return servant;
        }
    };
```

But this crashes the process with the following core dump

```
  [1] __exdbg_notify_of_unexpected(0xfffffc7ffad91640, 0x1, 0xfffffc7ffb849200, 0xfffffc7ffce202e0, 0x18, 0x101010101010101), at 0xfffffc7ffce07f90
  [2] __Crun::ex_chk_unexpected(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffc7ffce09234
  [3] Locator::preinvoke(this = 0x7c77f0, oid = CLASS, adapter = 0xdcf538, operation = 0xfffffc7ffad92740 "nextData", cookie = (nil)), line 238 in "locator.cpp"
  [4] TAO::Portable_Server::RequestProcessingStrategyServantLocator::locate_servant(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffc7ffd7521d2
```

1. Why doesn't the TAO library catch the exception I throw? I did quite a lot of googling on this and couldn’t find any solution to this. I throw this exception with reference to the example [here](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/C++-report-col14.pdf). I also tried returning NULL hoping that the NULL pointer exception checking at the caller function RequestProcessingStrategyServantLocator::locate_servant() in TAO would handle it. Even then I get the same core dump.
2. The other question I have is, why does preinvoke() is being called in the first place by TAO if I have already destroyed the servant and removed its reference. Can anyone show my a good example of how the this reference should be removed, so that preinvoke() would not be called?

**EDIT**

I'm using ACE TAO 6.0.7_x86

As suggested in @Johnny Willemsen 's reply I'm catching exception at client code, the place where server operation is being invoked. But its not being caught here. the code still crashes.

My client code looks like below

```
      try 
      {
        rs->getValue(tab.out()); 
      }
      catch (CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST& x) 
      {
          cout << "OMG OMG ERROR: CORBA  : " << x << endl;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very likely not catching the exception in your client code, the exception is passed back from the server to your client. In the TAO distribution see also TAO/tests/On_Demand_Activation for a unit tests for this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Johnny, I had a look at the example, and tried catching the example when calling run() of orb.

try{
orb->run();
}
catch (const CORBA::Exception& ex) {
cout << Exception Caught" << endl;
return -1;
}
But the process still crashes at the same point. Am I catching the exception at the right place?

Comment: You have to add the catch to the client code where you invoke the operation onto the server

Comment: Johnny, I have included try catch, the place where the server code is being called. But it still crashes. Is there a way to notify when a servant has been destroyed, so that preinvoke will not be called the first place